# Weird bug in c implementing schoolbook multiplication using gmp

Tags: c, for-loop, gmp

I have a weird problem.

I am trying to implement the schoolbook multiplication. I am aware that the function mpz_mul does that for me but it is my task to implement it myself as a homework.

So here is my code:

```
void mpz_school_mul(mpz_t c, mpz_t a, mpz_t b)
{
    size_t i;
    mp_limb_t b_i;
    mpz_t c_part;

    mpz_init(c_part);

    /* Backup a for the special case a := a * b. */
    mpz_t a_backup;

    mpz_init(a_backup);
    mpz_set(a_backup, a);
    /* Clear the result */
    mpz_set_ui(c,0);

    gmp_printf("i = %zx, size(b) = %zx, a = %Zx, b = %Zx\n", i, mpz_size(b), a, b);

    for(i = 0; i < mpz_size(b); i++)
    {
        printf("test\n");
        b_i = mpz_getlimbn(b,i);
        /* c = a*b_i*B^i + ... + a*b_0*B^0 */

            /* Calculate a*b_i for every round. */
            mpz_mul_limb(c_part,a_backup,b_i); 

            /* Shift it to the right position (*B^i). */
            mpz_mul_base(c_part,c_part,i);

            /* Sum all a*b_i*B^i */
            mpz_school_add(c, c, c_part);   
    }

    mpz_clear(a_backup);
    mpz_clear(c_part);
}
```

This code works well for me and i can test it with several parameters. The result is correct so I don't think I need to change to much in the calculation part. ;)

As example: This parameters work as intended.

```
mpz_set_str(a, "ffffffff00000000abcdabcd", 16);
mpz_set_str(b, "cceaffcc00000000abcdabcd", 16);
mpz_school_mul(c,a,b);
```

Now to the bug:

When i run the program with a parameter b with a zero limb (I'm using a 32 bit VM) at the end the program crashes:

```
mpz_set_str(a, "ffffffff00000000abcdabcd", 16);
mpz_set_str(b, "cceaffcc00000000", 16);
mpz_school_mul(c,a,b);
```

The output with this parameter b_0 = 0 is:

```
i = 0, size(b) = 2, a = ffffffff00000000abcdabcd, b = cceaffcc00000000
```

I think the for-loop stucks because the printf("test\n"); does not show up in this run.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Does your `school_add` function accept overlapping arguments? Your multiplication function doesn't...

Comment: May you help me out, what do you mean by overlapping arguemtents?

Comment: Sorry, sloppy wording. I mean a call like `mpz_school_add(c, c, c_part)` where the first two arguments are the same.

Comment: Yes, I checked this case. c = c + c_part in the mpz_school_add should work properly. Why do you say, that my multiplication does not do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, the first two arguments may be the same, but `c == b` is a problem.

Comment: What do you suggest, should I backup b as i did it with a? I reset c at the start of the program with mpz_set_ui(c,0); so if c == b, b should be resetted as well but as you see in my gmp_print b is okay.

Comment: I don't think, that's the problem here, but I would change that, yes. `libgmp` checks the passed pointers for equality to handle these cases, for example (and not by backing up the values unconditionally).

Comment: May you give me a hint, where I can find more information about your statement: "libgmp checks the passed pointers for equality to handle these cases"

Comment: You test `c==a` and so on to see if backing-up is necessary. I don't think, that's causing your problem here, but I can't find anything else in your code either. Maybe the other functions you wrote are causing the problem. Our discussion is a little off-topic and you have too little reputation to chat. Feel free to write me an email :)

Comment: I wrote wrappers to the normal functions from `libgmp` for your replacements and your code compiles and gives the correct results without crashing. The error is somewhere else, I think.

Comment: Thats every interesting. I really wonder why it crashes exactly at the for-loop every time.

Comment: That's a weird error because, if I read your question correctly, your program crashes either in `i = 0;` or `i < mpz_size(b);`, both of which should not happen. Just to make sure, would you mind replacing `printf("test\n");` by `fprintf(stderr, "test\n");`, so we can be certain that this point is never reached? If it is indeed the case that the `printf()` is never reached, then you need to check for memory corruption earlier (running your app with `valgrind` might help you then).

Comment: Do you include `<stdio.h>` _before_ you include `<gmp.h>`? If not, `gmp_printf` is not declared (my documentation says so, at least), you declare it implicitly, the call may corrupt your stack and the following `printf` call reads invalid memory... Just guessing, though.

Comment: Oh dear lord.. Thank you @cmaster for your hint with fprintf(stderr, "test\n"); it actually printed and i found the error within the mpz_mul_base(c_part,c_part,i); function... with parameter c_part = 0 it ran into an endless loop... holy moly.. I wrote wrapper to check a few cases for each function but missed the biggest. Thank you very much, both of you did a great job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug in the problem is fixed now.

Here is the solution:

I tested out to use fprintf(stderr, "test\n"); rather than printf("test\n"); and tested the code. It magically showed up the "test" in my console.
It may have to do with the wrong inclusion order of the  and  file.

As I had this problem with the print I didn't check my other functions.
Since I figured out, that the for-loop wasn't the problem I tested several prints after each command. I was able to detect the error in the void mpz_mul_base(mpz_t c, mpz_t a, mp_size_t i) function where I didn't check the case with c_part = 0. With this parameter the following code of the mpz_mul_base(c_part,c_part,i); function ran into an endless loop:

```
if(mpz_size(c) >= n)
    for(i = mpz_size(c); i >= n; i--)
    {
    mpz_setlimbn(c, clear, i);
    }
```

I replaced the >= with > and everything works fine now.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When answering your own question, you should still write up a full answer as comments are meant to be temporary. That would improve the quality of your post significantly -- if you could do so, that would be great. Thank you!